# Get index locations of 0s which are completely surrounded by 1s

Tags: r

I have a matrix like so:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
              1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), nrow = 12, ncol = 12)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
 [2,]    1    1    2    1    1    2    1    1    2     1     1     2
 [3,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    1    0     1     1     0
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
 [9,]    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    1    1     0     1     1
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
[11,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
[12,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
```

and I want to find the index locations where 0 is completely surrounded by 1s in a 3x3 window.  I can find all the zeros with:

`which(m == 0)` but this will also return places where a 2 surrounds a 0 such as at index location `m[3,3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
w <- which(m == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
w
#      row col
# [1,]   9   1
# [2,]   3   3
# [3,]   9   4
# [4,]   3   6
# [5,]   9   7
# [6,]   3   9
# [7,]   9  10
# [8,]   3  12
```

We don't need to know which zeroes are on a boundary, so filter out those:

```r
w <- w[ w[,1] > 1 & w[,1] < (nrow(m)-1) & w[,2] > 2 & w[,2] < (ncol(m)-1), ]
w
#      row col
# [1,]   3   3
# [2,]   9   4
# [3,]   3   6
# [4,]   9   7
# [5,]   3   9
# [6,]   9  10
```

Now we can take those inner indices and build 3x3 submatrices into a list. Here are the first couple (of six):

```r
Map(function(rn,cn) m[rn+(-1:1),cn+(-1:1)], w[,1], w[,2])[1:2]
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    1
# [2,]    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    1
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    1
```

Now we can just filter out the ones where there is only one non-`1` entry in the matrix.

```r
Filter(function(m3) sum(m3 != 1) == 1, Map(function(rn,cn) m[rn+(-1:1),cn+(-1:1)], w[,1], w[,2]))
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    1
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    1
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    1
```

Since you need to just count the occurrences, add `length(...)` around that, and you have your answer.

(If you're curious, the reason I went with `sum(m3!=1)==1` is because I wasn't certain if you wanted the border submatrices as well. If you wanted those, then the number of `1`s would be reduced, not "8" as a typical 3x3 would be. But we know that there should always be exactly one non-`1` in the submatrix: the center `0`.)

---

To get just the indices that match,

```r
w[mapply(function(rn,cn) sum(m[rn+(-1:1),cn+(-1:1)] != 1) == 1,
         w[,1], w[,2]),]
#      row col
# [1,]   9   4
# [2,]   9   7
# [3,]   9  10
```

Comment: I think this is close, but I don't want to simply count the occurrences, I want to return the index locations for all locations it occurs.